# Do you use a single project for client and server side for GWT based apps or separate project?

Tags: spring, gwt, tomcat

How do you have your GWT project setup? Do you have a single project for the client side and separate project for the server side? Can you share your experience with organizing projects for a GWT front end, spring backend system? I am looking to use Spring + GWT + Tomcat + Hibernate for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a really good reason to split the client and server side into multiple projects, you should go with just one project.

Otherwise, you'll need your server-side project to be dependent on your client-side project since any data objects that are shared will need to be part of the client (so gwt can create a javascript version of them).  This intuitively strikes me as backward.

Alternatively, you could create 3 projects; one server, one client, and one with all the shared classes. But doing that will give you two projects that gwt has to compile which you'll then have to wire back together. Unless you have to deal with some weird gwt-based legacy code integration issue, I can't see what this would get you.

Of the two significant gwt-based projects I've worked on (using the same technology stack you refer to), I have used a single project.

Answer (score 2):

I use a single project for a GWT client and Tomcat backend and it works great.  I love the convenience of making a quick change in protocol to both sides and then having a single build step.

The war directory in a GWT project can do all of the non-GWT stuff you're used to, with arbitrary directories and files, so it's really convenient to mix JSP, HTML, and normal JavaScript right in with GWT.